# Mostrar la información de un JSON usando Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview

Estoy intentando realizar una aplicación que mediante un JSON se me muestre la lista de valores, mediante un Recycle View usando Fragments. El problema lo tengo a la hora de recuperar los datos; no sé si es que me está fallando la función al obtener los datos o es que no los estoy asignando correctamente. He probado meter datos de un usuario en local, y se muestra, pero a la hora de intentar recuperar los datos del JSON no se me muestran, se ve el fragmento cargado pero no muestra la información.
PD he depurado y me he dado cuenta que al intentar llamar la función de *llenarlista()* accede a la función, pero falla al hacer la `new  JsonObjectRequest`, en vez de pasar por el `onResponse` se va directamente para el `queu.add(jsonArrayRequest)`.

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<Usuario> listaActividad;
RecyclerView recycle;
ListaTrabajadores fragmentolista = new ListaTrabajadores();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ponerFragmento(fragmentolista);



}
private  void ponerFragmento(Fragment fragmento){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.contenedor, fragmento);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
 }


  }
```

Fragment

```
public class ListaTrabajadores extends Fragment {

ArrayList<Usuario> listaFragment;
RecyclerView recycle;
private   adaptador myadapter;
private RequestQueue queu;

public ListaTrabajadores() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lista_trabajadores, container, false);
    recycle = vista.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recycle.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    listaFragment = new ArrayList<>();
     queu = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    llenarlista();

    return vista;
}
private void llenarlista() {


    String url = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key=5303976-fd6581ad4ac165d1b75cc15b3&q=kitten&image_type=photo&pretty=true";
    JsonObjectRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray= response.getJSONArray("hits");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String nombre = object.getString("user");
                        String imagen = object.getString("pageURL");
                        String apellido =object.getString("user");
                        String puesto=object.getString("tags");

                        listaFragment.add(new Usuario(imagen,nombre,puesto,apellido));

                    }

                    myadapter = new adaptador(getContext(), listaFragment);
                    recycle.setAdapter(myadapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }


    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            public void onErrorResponse (VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("tag", "onErrorResponse" + error.getMessage());
            }

    });
    queu.add(jsonArrayRequest);

}


 }
```

Adaptador

```
   public class adaptador extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adaptador.ViewHolderDatos > {
     @NonNull
        private Context contexto;
        ArrayList<Usuario> lista_usuario;

    public adaptador(Context context, @NonNull ArrayList<Usuario> listas) {
     contexto =context;
     lista_usuario = listas;

    }

      @Override
      public ViewHolderDatos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

       View view = LayoutInflater.from(contexto)
          .inflate(R.layout.elemento_lista,parent,false);
      return new ViewHolderDatos(view);
     }

   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderDatos holder, int position) {
    Usuario actual = lista_usuario.get(position);
    String nombre =actual.getNombre();
    String  genero = actual.getGenero();
    String puesto = actual.getPuesto();
    String url = actual.getImagen();

    holder.genero.setText(genero);
    holder.nombre.setText(nombre);
    holder.puesto.setText (puesto);
    Picasso.with(contexto).load(url).fit().centerInside().into(holder.imagen);


    }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
  return lista_usuario.size();
  }

     public class ViewHolderDatos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
     TextView nombre;
     TextView genero;
     ImageView imagen;
     TextView puesto;
     public ViewHolderDatos(View itemView) {
     super(itemView);
     nombre= itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombre);
     genero= itemView.findViewById(R.id.genero_valor);
     imagen= itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
     puesto = itemView.findViewById(R.id.puesto_valor);

   }

  }
```

Usuario

(Hay atributos que no se usan, que no les extrañe, los que quiero recuperar son los que están en el constructor)

```
  public class Usuario {
  private String imagen;
  private String nombre;
  private String apellido;
  private String puesto;
  private String altura;
  private String pais;
  private String edad;
  private String color;
  private String genero;

   public Usuario() {

 }

  public Usuario(String imagen, String nombre, String apellido, String puesto) {
  this.imagen = imagen;
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.apellido = apellido;
  this.puesto = puesto;
  }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
   return "Usuario{" +

          ", imagen='" + imagen + '\'' +
          ", nombre='" + nombre + '\'' +
          ", apellido='" + apellido + '\'' +
          ", puesto='" + puesto + '\'' +
          ", altura='" + altura + '\'' +
          ", pais='" + pais + '\'' +
          ", edad='" + edad + '\'' +
          ", color='" + color + '\'' +
          ", genero='" + genero + '\'' +
          '}';
      }



    public String getImagen() {
    return imagen;
  }

    public void setImagen(String imagen) {
    this.imagen = imagen;
   }

     public String getNombre() {
     return nombre;
   }

      public void setNombre(String nombre) {
      this.nombre = nombre;
     }

  public String getApellido() {
  return apellido;
  }

  public void setApellido(String apellido) {
  this.apellido = apellido;
  }

  public String getPuesto() {
  return puesto;
  }

 public void setPuesto(String puesto) {
  this.puesto = puesto;
  }

  public String getAltura() {
  return altura;
  }

  public void setAltura(String altura) {
  this.altura = altura;
  }

  public String getPais() {
  return pais;
  }

  public void setPais(String pais) {
  this.pais = pais;
  }

  public String getEdad() {
  return edad;
  }

  public void setEdad(String edad) {
  this.edad = edad;
  }

  public String getColor() {
  return color;
  }

  public void setColor(String color) {
  this.color = color;
  }

  public String getGenero() {
  return genero;
  }

  public void setGenero(String genero) {
  this.genero = genero;
  }
}
```

Os adjunto imagen de cómo me hace el request. Al no pasar por el `for` se me queda la lista vacía, además si os fijáis tengo puestos puntos de interrupción dentro del `for` y el primero y único en el que se para es en el de `queue.add(jsonArrayRequest)`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí os enseño qué es lo que me devuelve la url y el this

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Depura la respuesta del JSON y dinos si los datos están llegando a ese punto de tu programa.

Comment: Falla en la funcion llenarlista() accede a la funcion pero falla al hacer la new  JsonObjectRequest, en vez de pasar por el onResponse se va directamente para el queu.add(jsonArrayRequest) y le pasa la lista vacia. Alguien sabe el motivo del porque

Comment: No puede ser, si no entra en el `onResponse` entraría en el `onErrorResponse`, ¿revisaste el Logcat para ver si no te está imprimiendo algún error? ¿Por qué no haces log de `response` y verificas? Te aconsejo que aprendas a depurar si quieres ganar horas/días en el desarrollo del código. Cuando algo no funcione del modo esperado depúralo con Logcat o poniendo puntos de interrupción en el código.

Comment: Ya lo he depurado  con puntos de interrupcion por eso se que no llega  a la parte de llenar la lista y Salta desde el JSonObject Request al queu.add(jsonArrayRequest). Con respecto a errores en el log cat el unico que me da es el siguiente  E/le.willywonkar: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

Comment: ¿Y qué valor tienen tus objetos en esos puntos de interrupción?

Comment: Estan vacios porque no llega a pasar por el for ,se lo salta.

Comment: A ver, pon un punto de interrupción justo en esta línea: `JSONArray jsonArray= response.getJSONArray("hits");` y dinos si el código se detiene ahí y qué valor tiene `response` en ese caso.

Comment: Pongo el punto de interrupcion pero no llega a pararse porque no pasa por ahi el error parece que esta a la hora de hacer el request ,pero si fuera asi deberia ir al onErrorResponse(). No es si es que me falta algun parametro al hacer  el request.

Comment: ¿En el `onCreateView` del Fragmento sí entra? ¿Tienes puntos de interrupción ahí? De todos modos debes saber que cuando trabajes con `Volley` no debes nunca usar `return`, porque las peticiones que haces a Volley son asíncronas, de modo que, o implementas un callback o, desde dentro del `onResponse` de Volley pasas los datos a otra parte o llenas tus elementos en ese bloque.

Comment: Vale ahora si me devuelva si entra en el onErrorResponse().Y me devuelve este error java.net.SocketException: socket failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Comment: Vale ya he encontrado la solución era un tema de permisos que la aplicacion no los habia cogido

Comment: Ya me parecía raro que no entrase en el `onErrorResponse()`, es lo que debe hacer cuando la petición falla. ¿Quizá no estabas revisando en el LogCat de forma adecuada? Es importante hacerlo cuando depuras tu código o puedes perder días por algo tan simple.